# jquery fadeToggle and removeAttr functionality

Tags: jquery

Working url: http://runnerupapparel.com/building/

Upon clicking the "Info" or "Look" link everything works properly, but when clicking the x to close the panel, the link color is not going back to gray, #666. Also the other nav links not being available when fadeToggle is activated would be beautiful. Not exactly sure how to approach that one. Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#info").hide();
    $(".info").show();

    $('.info').click(function() {
        $("#info").fadeToggle();
        $(".info a").css({
            'color': '#d71635',
            'background': 'url(/building/images/bolt.png) left -23px no-repeat',
            'position': 'relative',
            'z-index': '9998'
        });
        $(".info").css({
            'background': 'url(/building/images/bolt.png) right -23px no-repeat',
            'position': 'relative',
            'z-index': '9999'
        });
    });

    $('.closeinfo').click(function() {
        $(".info a").removeAttr('style');
        $(".info").removeAttr('style');
        $("#info").fadeToggle();
    });

    $("#look").hide();
    $(".look").show();

    $('.look').click(function() {
        $("#look").fadeToggle();
        $(".look a").css({
            'color': '#d71635',
            'background': 'url(/building/images/bolt.png) left -23px no-repeat',
            'position': 'relative',
            'z-index': '9998'
        });
    });

    $('.closelook').click(function() {
        $(".look a").removeAttr('style');
        $("#look").fadeToggle();
    });

});​
```

Comment: The attribute gets removed correctly. You could maybe use `Cufon.refresh()` to refresh also the canvas...

Comment: use classes in css instead of inline, will make coding a lot simpler using `addClass(), removeClass() ` or toggleClass()`. It is far simpler to remove!!

Answer (score 0):

so from what i can tell heres what i would do:

in you .css file (or however you manage your default styles) make two different classes for each one of your links. once you have that done. you can then use the .toggleClass("newClass") method to toggle back and forth. this should get rid of the color not going back to grey when you click the either of the links twice. then also when you click the x button you can change the class of all the links to the class that makes them grey: `$('.selector').attr('class','newClass')`

in response to the problem of not being able to click on the other links when you have either the info or look panel showing is caused by height issue. i visited the site which you provided and entered the "inspector" mode and played around with your css properties. when i uncheck the height property that is set for 454px the problem went away. so just set a height that is much smaller than you have set now and that should work.

Comment: Appreciate all the help thank you guys. Getting closer. I was able to attach a class to the clicked link, but I can't seem to activate the regular class upon close. Here is the code:

Comment: the regular class as in 'inforegular'?

Comment: Yes sir, we have .info ahover/.infohover upon hover, then .inforegular /.inforegular(both identical) that should be applied to .info/.info upon .closeinfo click. Hope that makes sense..

Comment: good! glad to see it working. now currently it looks like all you have to do is make it so if you click on info or look and the fadeToggle function should also be called